# SwiperJs circular slide

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

I want create circular carousel with SwiperJs. but I could not :(

[image]

This is design. I want slides circular. Can I do that with SwiperJs?

This is my HTML:

```
                                <div class="swiper controller-slider">
                                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                                        <div class="swiper-slide" data-title="KOSGEB" data-desc="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. ">
                                            <div class="item">
                                                <img src="./assets/images/controllers/controller-4.png" alt="">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="swiper-slide" data-title="Türkiye Cumhuriyeti Ticaret Bakanlığı" data-desc="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. ">
                                            <div class="item">
                                                <img src="./assets/images/controllers/controller-1.png" alt="">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="swiper-slide" data-title="Türkiye Cumhuriyeti Ticaret Bakanlığı" data-desc="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. ">
                                           <div class="item">
                                               <img src="./assets/images/controllers/controller-2.png" alt="">
                                           </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="swiper-slide" data-title="TÜBİTAK" data-desc="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. ">
                                            <div class="item">
                                                <img src="./assets/images/controllers/controller-3.png" alt="">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="swiper-slide" data-title="Sanayi Sanayi Başkanlığı" data-desc="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. ">
                                            <div class="item">
                                                <img src="./assets/images/controllers/controller-5.png" alt="">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="swiper-slide" data-title="Türkiye Cumhuriyeti Ticaret Bakanlığı" data-desc="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. ">
                                            <div class="item">
                                                <img src="./assets/images/controllers/controller-6.png" alt="">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

And this is my JS codes:

```js
 const slide = new Swiper(item, {
            centeredSlides: true,
            loop:true,
            slideToClickedSlide:true,
            pagination: {
                el: ".controller-slider-wrapper .swiper-pagination",
                clickable: true,
                renderBullet: function renderBullet(index, className) {
                    return '<span class="' + className + '">' + "</span>";
                }
            },
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: 10,
            breakpoints: {
                768: {
                    slidesPerView: 4,
                },
                1200: {
                    slidesPerView: 5,
                },
                1400: {
                    slidesPerView: 6,
                },
            },
        });

        slide.on('slideChange', function (e) {
            handleSlideChange(slide)
        });

        slide.on('progress', function (e) {
            handleProgress(slide)
        });
```

and this is looks like:
[image]

I try use onProgress events. Try somethings but it did not worked. Please help me!

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried and describe in what way it doesn't do what you require.

Comment: It is more a "freelancer" mission (This is not a Q).